# Passing ResponseListener to Request class getting error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, response, httpresponse

I'm new in creating Android apps. What I want to do is to pass variable to php service and get true or false. This is my code

```
package com.fishingtournaments.tournamentapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView ats;
 EditText qrCode_edit;
 Button check_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ats = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_textView);
    qrCode_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qrCode_editText);
    check_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_button);


    check_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String qrCode = qrCode_edit.getText().toString();
            //ats.setText(qrCode);
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success){

                            ats.setText("Toks vartotojas yra");

                        }else{
                            ats.setText("Tokio vartotojo nera");

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };


            LoginRequest loginRequest;
            loginRequest = new LoginRequest(qrCode, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue;
            queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });
}

}
```

This is my LoginRequest class

```
    package com.fishingtournaments.tournamentapp;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by manta on 2017-02-08.
 */

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    public static String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://suvalkijossapalas.devpanda.eu/checkQr.php";
    public Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String qrcode, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params.put("qrCode",qrcode);
    }

    public Map<String,String> getParams(){
        return params;
    }

}
```

When I try to run app on emulator and press Check button my app crashes and I get this error:

```
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
```

> 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.put(java.lang.Object,
>   java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                           at
>   com.fishingtournaments.tournamentapp.LoginRequest.(LoginRequest.java:19)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.fishingtournaments.tournamentapp.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:64)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

I think this might problem with:
 `loginRequest = new LoginRequest(qrCode, responseListener);` I think it crashes because of the responseListener.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `LoginRequest` code. Specifically this line:

```
params.put("qrCode",qrcode);
```

Here the `params` field equals to `null`.
You declare correctly your `params` field as a `Map<String String>` but you never create a new instance of `Map<String, String>` to hold the data.

You will have to initialise your field in the constructor, like this:

```
public LoginRequest(String qrcode, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new Map<String, String();
    params.put("qrCode",qrcode);
}
```

Or initialise the field immediately after declaring it, like this:

```
public static String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://suvalkijossapalas.devpanda.eu/checkQr.php";
public Map<String, String> params = new Map<String, String>();
```